# Upgraded EF5.x to EF6.1.3, strange migration changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing EF5 project that I upgraded to EF6.1.3.  If I do an "Add-Migration" while on EF5 I get an empty migration, as expected, but after I upgrade to EF6 and "add-migration" I get a bunch of strange changes.  The only thing that's consistent is, there is a many-to-many table that wasn't defined in EF/migrations ever before, it appears a past dev created it manually, and now it looks like EF6 found it and decided to acknowledge it by trying to rename the table and I don't know why.  Here's the strange changes it wants to perform

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.DashboardUserDashboards", newName: "DashboardDashboardUsers");
RenameTable(name: "dbo.DashboardOrganizationAdjunctDashboardProcesses", newName: "DashboardProcessDashboardOrganizationAdjuncts");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DashboardProcessTaskTriggers", name: "DaysOfWeek", newName: "__mig_tmp__0");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DashboardProcessTaskTriggers", name: "DaysOfWeek1", newName: "DaysOfWeek");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DashboardProcessTaskTriggers", name: "__mig_tmp__0", newName: "DaysOfWeek1");
```

I never ran these, and the codebase ran fine, I added a new migration, which was empty, where I added an unrelated Stored Proc, which also ran fine & code executed.  But now when I run the codebase I get the exception

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.DashboardDashboardUsers'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.DashboardDashboardUsers'.
```

I searched the entire solution and that bad table name/object is never referenced anywhere in the codebase, nor has the DB been changed (as I commented out the code).  How can I resolve this error as something is hardcoded to it, but it's not inside any .cs file anywhere?  Out of desperation, I even added the rename to my migration, then after it, renamed it back, but that still gives the error.  The only way to fix the exception was to let the rename execute, which I absolutely do not want because it's breaking our naming convention and this codebase has been in production for years and it's not an acceptable change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your issues come from EF6 applying different conventions than EF5 when the configurations are not explicitly defined in the code. So you can try to define those configurations explicitly. You can do this in the `OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext` class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    ...
    <your configurations here>
}
```

I can think of a couple things to try:

- Set the schema explicitly:

  ```
  modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
  ```

  Looks like your schema name is `dbo`. Notice that in your `RenameTable` sentences the table names are different but also the old name includes the schema prefix but the new name doesn't.
- Configure the mappings for the many-to-many relationships:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasMany(x => x.Dashboards)
      .WithMany(x => x.Users)
      .Map(x => { 
          x.MapRightKey("UserId"); 
          x.MapLeftKey("DashboardId"); 
          x.ToTable("DashboardUserDashboards"); 
       } );
  ```

  The key part here is the `.ToTable("DashboardUserDashboards")` configuration that sets the table physical name explicitly. For the other configurations I am making some assumptions about your model classes, as you didn't show that code, for instance that you have navigation properties `User.Dashboards` and `Dashboard.Users`. Perhaps you don't have those navigation properties, because you don't need them. You have to adapt that code to your specific model classes.

If you have a lot of EF configuration code it is better to use a mapping class for each entity, extending the `EntityTypeConfiguration` class with a type parameter which is your model class:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public Map()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Dashboards)
             ...
    }
}
```

This is a typical `OnModelCreating`method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("auth");
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
}
```

By using `Configurations.LoadFromAssembly` you apply all the configurations you defined in your EntityTypeConfiguration classes. Also you can define some explicit conventions and apply them with `Conventions.LoadFromAssembly`.

EF6 mappings and conventions are very powerful. In msdn you can find detailed info about [configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) and [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks, I've been going through your suggests and they are helping, one bit at a time.  My next problem is why is EF dropping, then recreating indexes, on tables that already have an index on that column in a past migration.

Comment: If the migration code doesn't show any hint about why the indexes are being recreated then you can try looking at the SQL generated by EF: run `Update-Database`with the parameter `-Script`. This will generate the SQL without  executing the migration. Look what changes in the new index: name, schema, order of the columns. Set an explicit configuration for it in your code.